# Префиксы Firefox для прокрутки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, прокрутка, кроссбраузерность

На странице https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-scrollbars-ru указано как добавить стили панелей прокрутки для Firefox.

Мне необходимо добавить стили для панели прокрутки для как можно большего числа версий Firefox насколько это возможно. Каким образом нужно задавать префиксы для Firefox типа `moz-` (см. https://zarabotat-na-sajte.ru/uroki-html/css/vendornye-prefiksy.html) для задания скроллбара?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для версии Firefox до 64-ой вы можете пробовать модифицировать файл userChrome.css для стилизации панели прокрутки, а также других элементов интерфейса. Для этого стоит подключить файл пространства имён XML с официального сайта Mozilla (локально или с сайта Mozilla) с помощью правила  `@namespace`, ***которое нужно объявить после всех правил `@import` и `@charset`, но перед всеми остальными At-rules***.

Попробуйте использовать следующий код

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* один раз прописать эту строчку */

:-moz-any(#content,#appcontent) browser{
  здесь ваши правила
}
```

[О применении пользовательских стилей в интерфейсах Firefox](https://www.userchrome.org/adding-style-recipes-userchrome-css.html)

---

Вы можете использовать `scrollbar-width` и `scrollbar-color` для браузеров Firefox старше версии 64.

Вам нужно описать эти свойства для нужных Вам элементов (если нужен только вертикальный скроллбар для всей страницы, то можно указать `scrollbar-width` и `scrollbar-color` для `body`).

Как их испольлзовать описано в данных статьях:

1. [CSS Scrollbars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars)
2. [Ширина скроллбара](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width)
3. [Цвета для скроллбара](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color)

Такой же вопрос на английской версии: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/54101063#54101063

Comment: если Вы ставите минус, то подскажите, в чем я не прав, чтобы я смог давать более подходящую информацию

Comment: это не я минусовал.

Comment: Минус не я поставил, но предполагаю что он заслужен ответом на постронний вопрос (не на тот, который был задан) - то есть, тут отвечается на _«нужны ли такие префиксы для фаерфокса старше версии 64?»_. Но вопрос-то задан именно о вендорных префиксах, а значит и ответы должны быть о вендорных префиксах (независимо от того, нужны ли они сейчас!). Почему так: потому что **stackoverflow это база знаний**, а не сервис решения индивидуальных задач. В этой базе ответы часто находят поиском. И те люди, которые будут искать ответ на тот же самый вопрос - не найдут в данном ответе нужной им информации.

Comment: Другими словами: конечно же, ты поступил правильно, сообщив в ответе о том что вендорные префиксы в актуальном FF уже не нужны. Но это все же _дополнительная_ в контексте вопроса информация, и она _не должна заменять собой основную_. В таких случаях (когда инфа не является ответом, но может помочь автору), я обычно пишу в комментарии... это тоже не очень поощряется, т.к. комменты предназначены только для уточнений - но если не злоупотреблять - то можно. А этот ответ, можно улучшить (исправить) всего лишь добавив в него список тех самых злосчастных префиксов для старых версий фаерфокса.

Comment: @yar85 благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, буду внимательнее впредь ;)

Comment: @yar85 вроде бы нашел подходящее решение

Comment: Решение очень необычное и интересное, да и вообще много полезной и нужной информации (от меня уж точно плюсик).

Comment: Дополнение: судя [по багтрекеру](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541233), решение должно работать до **69** версии Firefox. Вот только не совсем ясно как будут вести себя версии 60..68 при комбинации обычных стилей (у 60+ есть поддержка `scrollbar-width` с `scrollbar-color`) и стилей из userChrome.css... то есть какие браузер сочтет приоритетными - но когда стилизация одинакова, это в принципе совсем неважно.

Comment: @yar85 поправлю цифру сейчас )